# Keeping the first N elements of a std::vector<> and removing the rest

Tags: c++, vector

I have a `std::vector<int>` variable in my `C++` application. The size of the vector is determined at runtime, but is typically about `1000`.

I have sorted this vector (which works well), and after sorting, I would like to keep only the first `50` elements.

I have tried:

```
kpts.erase(kpts.begin() + 50, kpts.end());
```

where `kpts` is my vector, and the performance is horrible! Presumably because of the way `erase` operates.

**Is there a way to only keep the first `50` elements of a vector?** It seems like it should be obvious, but I can't find a way to do this.

Comment: How do you know the performance is horrible? If you only want the first 50 sorted elements, use `std::partial_sort`.

Comment: I need to sort first, then keep the first 50 elements.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Yes, you can use `std::vector::resize`, which just truncates if the length of the vector is greater than n.

See here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/

```
std::vector<int> myvector;

for (int i=1;i<1000;i++) myvector.push_back(i);

myvector.resize(50);
// myvector will contain values 1..50
```

Comment: This can't really be any more efficient. The complexity of `erase` is linear in the size of that spot to the end, whereas `resize` is linear in the size of the vector.

Comment: Perfect! I thought it should be simple. I'm just starting to get into `C++` so I apologize if it's a naive question. Appreciate the help though! I'll accept as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: @chris, they're both O(n), but resize is cleaner (imho.) Also, *marginally* more efficient in practice since you don't have to call begin() and end() to get the iterators.

Comment: @Moritz, Yes indeed, but if `erase` performs "horribly", then `resize` will undoubtedly do the same. I still haven't seen a basis for that horrible performance claim, however.

Comment: @chris
I don't understand why would erase perform horribly. It doesn't make sense. Want to see benchmarks, profiling, compilation optimization level and compiler please.

Comment: @zehelvion, I don't even remember making the comment at this point, but I assume I was quoting the OP and assuming they had good reason for saying it. The question says, "the performance is horrible!"

Comment: @chris Yeah, I'm just "supporting" what you said initially. The questions motive doesn't seem to be well funded at best.

Comment: `resize` can also grow the vector. Even if your program logic prevents that from happening, it means that for `std::vector<T>`, `T` needs to be default constructable. `erase` just requires `T` to be moveable (which I think is a requirement of vectors anyhow)